# UIWebView show alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have `UIWebView` and i load `google.com` to it:

```
[self.webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];

NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
[[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

In the finish method i call this method to show alert on the webview but it won't work.any idea what can be the issue?

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('Hello')"];
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are creating Cocoa/OSX application using WebKit/WebView instead of iOS Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WebKit/WebView in OSX, this class never shows JavaScript's alert.
Instead, it calls WebUIDelegate's method below

```
func
webView(
    _ sender: WebView!
,   runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String!
,   initiatedBy frame: WebFrame!
) {
}
```

if you set webView's uiDelegate property.

```
self.webView.uiDelegate = self
```

You may show your own panel with the message provided in this callback.